# What are the final weights of the model with EarlyStopping callback?

Tags: python-3.x, keras

In `EarlyStopping` callback I set `patience=10`. What does it mean actually?
For example, let's suppose that from the epoch 20 and onwards the model is not decreasing loss till the epoch 30. What epoch's weights are saved, epoch 30 or epoch 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on `restore_best_weights` parameter of the `EarlyStopping` callback. By default, it is set to `False` which means that the final weights will be the weights of the epoch 30. If it is set to `True`, the final weights will be the weights of epoch 20.

You can read more about `EarlyStopping` parameters [there](https://keras.io/callbacks/).